# Substituting a list of values into a function

Tags: pattern-matching

```
g[p_] := Mod[19^(-1 + p), p^2]
```

This is my function, and the set of values I have is the first 999 prime numbers. I made a table listing the first 999 prime numbers, but I want to sub each of the values in this table into my function and produce a list/table of all of the solutions.
How do I do this?

Comment: Please refer to: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data** in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). As you receive **give back**, vote & answer questions. Keep the site useful, be kind, give context, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question was put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do anything , your function will work with lists as defined as all the functions within it are listable:

```
g[p_] := Mod[19^(-1 + p), p^2]


g[Range@25]
```

> > {0, 3, 1, 11, 21, 19, 1, 59, 64, 79, 89, 91, 1, 19, 46, 219, 69, 307, 
> >     0, 379, 361, 459, 392, 379, 421}

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) `Map`,

```
primelist = Array[Prime, 999];

g[p_] := Mod[19^(-1 + p), p^2];

solutions = Map[g, primelist];
```

You could also use shorthand and type it as `solutions = g /@ primelist`